# FileLoadException when trying to load a signed Assembly with VersionInformation (C#, WPF, AssemblyVersion, Asterisk)

Tags: c#, wpf, signed, fileloadexception

I have a problem when trying to load a signed assembly into my WPF application. Specifically when the WPF Views are created, e.g.

```
var circularProgressControl = new CircularProgressControl();
```

I get this error

System.IO.FileLoadException: "Could not load file or assembly 'Projectname, Version=1.5.8615.20370, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f619059777d70c90' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

I could enclose the problem to the point that the signed assembly has this version information:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.5.*")]
```

It works fine when I don't use the asterisk:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.5")]
```

Can anyone help with this issue? Is the asterisk incompatible with signed assembly loading or ist this a bug in the environment?

Problem:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.5.*")]

var circularProgressControl = new CircularProgressControl(); --> FileLoadException
```

No Problem:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.5")] 

var circularProgressControl = new CircularProgressControl(); --> No FileLoadException
```

Comment: How are you loading your assembly? with a reference? `assembly.load` ? Do you know precisely what assembly that fails? the *or one of its dependencies*-bit can make debugging quite a bit more complicated.

Comment: Not me directly. It's done in the code behind, which I assume will use some basic Windows API functions or so (HRESULT). Yes I know the assembly and I can change the AssemblyVersionInfo but I need to know if the asterisk is allowed or not and if this is maybe a bug?